# Fetch all cloudwatch logs irrespective of number of records using python3 boto

Tags: python, amazon-cloudwatch

Is it possible to fetch all cloudwatch logs from a particular log group?
As per AWS there is limit of 10000 records per query execution but I would like to fetch all records irrespective of any numbers

Any module or functionality of Python that can solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

Use [this source](https://gist.github.com/eldondevcg/fffff4b7909351b19a53) as example, be warned that this operation may be pretty expensive.
'NextToken' is a key to solve response limit.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
I do also need to run cloud watch query which will do parsing of the logs can be possible to do via your solution as I am not aware of if we can put query in get_log_events :)

Comment: I believe in this case you should use boto3 [start_query](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.26.83/reference/services/logs/client/start_query.html) or [get_query_results](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.26.83/reference/services/logs/client/get_query_results.html) methods

Comment: Yes that's true but it seems for getting query results there is limit of 10000 records from As service quota side.I could divide 4 weeks into 1 hour interval and fetch logs for these intervals but that operation would be too heavy :).

Comment: In response with first 10k records you also get NextToken value. Put this value in the second response and you'll get second 10k records and a new NextToken. Repeat until NextToken is empty, that means all records were fetched. Please look at the example provided it the answer